# replace character in query string via .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

My client wants a query string munged (by changing % to A) on certain pages.

For example, I can remove the query string completely on the desired pages via:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !="" 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SpecialPage(.*) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1? [R=301,L] #remove query string
```

Here's what I thought should remove % on the query string and replace with A but it's not:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\%(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SpecialPage(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1A%2  [L]
```

What am I doing wrong in this? I just can't quite spot it. Thanks for the expert eyes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're real close.

The problem here is that you've got a condition and the match of your rule should be together. Your backreference to the previous `RewriteCond` is broken because it's for the **REQUEST_URI** and *not* the **QUERY_STRING** like you want.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/SpecialPage(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1A%2  [L]
```

Here, the **%1** backreference matches the `(.*)` at the end of the `/SpecialPage` URI. The backreferences from your query string match gets lost, and that's the ones you really want. You can combine the condition to match the REQUEST_URI with the regular expression pattern in the `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\%(.*)$
RewriteRule ^SpecialPage(.*)$ /SpecialPage$1?%1A%2  [L]
```

Here, the **%1** and **%2** backreferences correctly reference the query string and the `SpecialPage` condition in the URI is met by the regex pattern.

Comment: Okay, I think I follow this, but I get an internal server error on that. I could have this: http://domain.com/SpecialPage?x=y%ff%dd%gqf312%ggg and my client wants those % to be 'A', e.g. http://domain.com/SpecialPage?x=yAffAddAgqfe312Aggg

Comment: Those are URL encoded escapes (the %ff, %dd, etc), so when they get to the rewrite engine, they will be decoded.

Comment: right. those are encoded, but i was hoping (well my client was) that they could still manipulate; so thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

## Redirect Query String

RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)=(.*)$
        RewriteRule ^(.*)?(.*)$ /$1--%0? [R=301,L]

From Url: http://localhost/sholay-slide.jsp?slide=2
To Url: http://localhost/sholay-slide.jsp--slide=2